# Python: Decimals with trigonometric functions

Tags: python, math, floating-point, decimal, trigonometry

I'm having a little problem, take a look:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(math.pi)
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

This is not what I learnt in my Calculus class (It was 0, actually)

So, now, my question:

I need to perform some heavy trigonometric calculus with Python. What library can I use to get correct values?

Can I use Decimal?

EDIT:

Sorry, What I mean is other thing.

What I want is some way to do:

```
>>> awesome_lib.sin(180)
0
```

or this:

```
>>> awesome_lib.sin(Decimal("180"))
0
```

I need a libraray that performs good trigonometric calculus. Everybody knows that sin 180° is 0, I need a library that can do that too.

Comment: "Can I use Decimal?" No. Pi is irrational.

Comment: The relevant question is:  what, exactly, are you planning to use this library for?  That will determine whether you actually need symbolic calculation, or whether there is some less heavyweight way to do what you want.  You really should read the "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic" link on @Zhenya's answer.

Comment: Actually, the answer you get is *correct* because `math.pi` is the closest floating point number to pi, but not pi itself! You should read the link on floating point arithmetic again if needed.

Comment: What good would it do you to have a library that returned the values of trigonometric functions of arguments in degrees? Although sine(180º) is zero, only a few special arguments have trigonometric values that are rational (and representable in floating-point). Almost every sine of a representable floating-point value is not a representable floating-point value. So you are going to have small errors, as you observed for sine of (almost) pi, even when you use degrees. So we need to know more about what you are trying to accomplish before we can give you good answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`1.2246467991473532e-16` is close to 0 -- there are 16 zeroes between the decimal point and the first significant digit -- much as `3.1415926535897931` (the value of `math.pi`) is close to pi. The answer is correct to sixteen decimal places!

So if you want `sin(pi)` to equal 0, simply round it to a reasonable number of decimal places. 15 looks good to me and should be plenty for any application:

```
print round(math.sin(math.pi), 15)
```

Comment: I forgot to thank you for your answer. You're soooo right. If PI is not an "exact" value, how could I wait sin(PI) to be an exact value? Sorry seems like I am too dumb. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 13):

Pi is an [irrational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) so it can't be represented exactly using a finite number of bits. However, you can use some library for symbolic computation such as [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

```
>>> sympy.sin(sympy.pi)
0
```

Regarding the second part of you question, if you want to use degrees instead of radians you can define a simple conversion function

```
def radians(x):
    return x * sympy.pi / 180
```

and use it as follows:

```
>>> sympy.sin(radians(180))
0
```

Comment: That's pretty slick, I didn't know `sympy` could do that.

Answer (score 7):

If you find the result unexpected, I dare suggesting that you have a look at this text: 
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

It's really worth it.

Comment: I've read it. Thanks! I already know the problems involving floating-points numbers. That's why i'm asking this.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try gmpy or real

in gmpy you can specify the precision explicitly:

```
    gmpy.pi(256)
```

in real.py you could use the pa() function:

```
    from real import pa,pi
    pa(pi)
```

Comment: Using a more precise value for pi will give a more precise result, but it won't necessarily lead to an *accurate* result.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer -**
Decimal.cos() and Decimal.sin() can both be implemented from Decimal.exp() implementation by splitting all even terms into the cos() function and all the odd terms into the sin() function and alternating the sign of each term between positive and negative in both of those series. No change needed in the loop which only computes N terms based on configured precision (Decimal.getcontext().prec).

**Long Answer -**
Python decimal.Decimal supports exp() function that takes only a real number argument (unlike exp() in R language) and computes the infinite series only up to the number of terms based on configured precision (decimal.Decimal.getcontext().prec).

Currently the even terms compute cosh() and the odd terms compute sinh(). Their sum is returned as the result of exp(). If the sign of each term was modified to alternate between positive and negative within each series, the even-terms-series will compute cos() and the odd-terms-series would compute sin().

Additionally, like R language, this change could enable Decimal.exp() to support complex arguments, so that exp(1j*x) could return Decimal.cos(x) + 1j * Decimal.sin(x).